# Construct multi table database query using multiple returned column values as parameters

Tags: mysql, database

I am putting together a system to provide car servicing quotes using the service code displayed by the car.

The vehicles are all made by the same manufacturer, the service codes are not model specific and indicate which set of jobs make up the service.
The price of each job varies depending upon the model of the vehicle and the engine type fitted.

There are 4 tables involved in getting the necessary information:

- vrm - Contains vehicle details. Returns model and engine variant from licence plate
- chassis - Has a column for each job containing a cost value for that
  job. Each row is a different model.
- engine - Identical to chassis but each row is a different engine.
- svs_codes - Has a column for each job with values of 1 or NULL to
  identify which jobs apply to that code. Each row is a different
  service code.

The query needs to obtain the engine and model numbers from the licence plate, return the jobs which are `NOT NULL` from the service code. Then using the values returned from those queries return the prices for those jobs from the engine and chassis tables.

The point I struggled with was how to only return columns from the engine and chassis tables based upon which columns held `NOT NULL` values in the svs_codes table?

I started out trying to use left joins but I couldn't get the result I wanted. I ended up adding a `SET` column to svs_codes which contains all the relevant jobs for each code. I created a stored procedure which gets the values from this column and `CONCAT`s them all together to create a new query which only returns the listed columns.

```
BEGIN
SET @code = (SELECT col FROM svs_codes WHERE code=svsCode);
SET @add = REPLACE(@code, ',' , '+');
SET @car = (SELECT concat(SUBSTR(vin, 4, 3), SUBSTR(engine, 1, 3)) FROM vrm WHERE vrm=regNo);
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ', @code, ', (', @add, ') AS total FROM svsview WHERE chassis=', (SELECT SUBSTRING(@car, 1, 3)), ' AND engine=', (SELECT SUBSTRING(@car, 4, 3)), ' LIMIT 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I created a `VIEW` which the stored procedure is run against. This is a `JOIN` of the chassis and engine tables with values for each column added together. Although my solution works, it seems a bit Heath Robinson. Have I totally over complicated this and is there a better way?

Demo with sample data for each table and recreation of my view is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1d4f10/2/0)

Comment: Hi. If you want matching rows from 2 tables where a right column is not null, that's an inner join on/where that column is not null. If the column is compared to a left column in a way that it being null fails then you don't need an explicit is not null. Left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So you need to have in mind the inner join for any outer join. If you are confused about a particular step, ask a question about that step, not the whole thing.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the comment, but what I am trying to achieve is return a single row consisting of only the columns from table b and table c which are not null in another single row in table a. I do not want the data from table a returned and there may be many null columns. I was conscious that my post was already lengthy so included a link to an sqlfiddle containing all tables and data instead of including it directly in my post

Comment: Thanks I saw the (useful) fiddle. Your code returns a sum but your descriptions don't. Please edit your question (not comments) to clearly say what is output per input. PS What is the source of svs_codes? It is poorly designed for anything but final display to a human. Because it's pivoted & MySQL has no (un)pivot you do have to write a query mentioning all its columns--hardwired for fixed column set, otherwise prepared from metadata (either the database's or the given redundant concatenated col column). Why isn't col computed or part of a view? Consider a view/subquery unpivoting svs_codes.

Comment: @philipxy Apologies, I thought I had explained my `VIEW` adequately in my post. The `SELECT` statement in my fiddle recreates the `VIEW` I am querying in my stored procedure. The stored procedure is preparing a query using the values from the `col` column. It works, but it didn't seem like the **right** way to do it. I'll read up on unpivoting tables, thanks for the tip.

Comment: As I said, your question is not so clear. It would be helpful if you just gave initial input & desired output then explained & illustrated the steps (eg adding col, defining a view) of your process. I see rereading your question that I can envision that but it good if you made your question clearer. A [mcve], which is obligatory, would be helpful. In answer to your question, per researching unpivoting, clearer code would be just looping to make tables where column names are data values like they should be since you want to ask about some per criteria or to aggregate on them.